# flex togglebuttonbar buttons width

Tags: apache-flex, button, togglebuttonbar

How could i use percentage width for buttons at tooglebuttonbar, because i dont want to use the width property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set percentage width of a component:

1. In MXML, you can set the [width](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/core/UIComponent.html#width)
   property using a percentage value.
2. In AS3, use the [percentWidth](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/core/UIComponent.html#percentWidth)
   property.

However, if you want to set the percentage width of buttons in a toggleButtonBar you can look at the [buttonWidth](http://www.few.vu.nl/~eliens/assets/flex3/langref/mx/controls/ButtonBar.html#style:buttonWidth) style, but I suspect that doesn't accept percentages.  If not, you're going to have to extend the component and re-write the updateDisplayList() method to size and position the buttons based on a percentage.

Comment: Hi, could you explain to me the hard part? how could i implement the percentage property for the button in the updateDisplayList if the button doesn't have this property?

Comment: Create a new component extending button bar.  Add the property to your extended component "public var buttonWidthPercentage : int", just like you would create any other property.  Then override updateDisplay list and calculate the button percentage width based on the unscaledWidth argument.